# How to convert binding value type into another in aspx?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, data-binding

I have this code:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxAppStatus" runat="server" Text="Done" Checked='<%# Bind("Status") %>'/>
```

The problem is that `Bind("Status")` returns string (True/False), don't know why though it was defined as `Boolean` in the entity model.

Is there a way to convert `Bind("Status")` into `Boolean` value and still using `Bind` (I need to edit this value not just show it and I think using `Bind` is the right way to do it automatically instead of doing it by `C#` code).

Answer (score 0):

I had once the same problem in ASP.Net, but using ADO.Net. I had to map a column that stored Y/N to a checkbox, and the solution was to simply convert the char(1) column to a bit using `cast((case when YesNoColumn = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as bit)` in the select statement, and the binding worked correctly. This, however, requires that the insert and update statements be also modified accordingly. I am not sure how this can be done in Entity Framework though.